# How to call a .NET Webservice from Android using KSOAP2?

Tags: android, ksoap2, ksoap

I have a problem while calling a webservice. I have a .NET web service on the server, and I am using KSOAP2 (ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2) in Android. While running the program I got an runtime exception like "org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive". What should I do?

Here is my code.

```
package projects.ksoap2sample;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ksoap2sample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.19/TestWeb/WebService.asmx";
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            //request.addProperty("prop1", "myprop");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

            String[] results = (String[])  result;
            tv.setText( ""+results[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, you should format your code by selecting it in the editor and clicking the toolbar icon with the ones and zeros. It indents by four spaces, which is the Markdown code for <pre/>

Comment: Are you still having problems with this? If so, then post the complete exception.

Comment: You also might want to consider this getting started tutorial on KSOAP Android [http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) Hope this helps you

Answer (score 24):

It's very simple. You are getting the result into an `Object` which is a primitive one.

Your code:

```
Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
```

Correct code:

```
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

//To get the data.
String resultData=result.getProperty(0).toString();
// 0 is the first object of data.
```

I think this should definitely work.

Answer (score 14):

How does your .NET Webservice look like?

I had the same effect using [ksoap 2.3 from code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). I followed the tutorial on [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/CallWebServiceFromkSOAP.aspx) (which is great BTW.)

And everytime I used

```
    Integer result = (Integer)envelope.getResponse();
```

to get the result of a my webservice (regardless of the type, I tried Object, String, int) I ran into the `org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive` exception.

I found a solution (workaround). The first thing I had to do was to remove the "SoapRpcMethod() attribute from my webservice methods.

```
    [SoapRpcMethod(), WebMethod]
    public Object GetInteger1(int i)
    {
        // android device will throw exception
        return 0;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public Object GetInteger2(int i)
    {
        // android device will get the value
        return 0;
    }
```

Then I changed my Android code to:

```
    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

However, I get a SoapPrimitive object, which has a "value" filed that is private. Luckily the value is passed through the `toString()` method, so I use `Integer.parseInt(result.toString())` to get my value, which is enough for me, because I don't have any complex types that I need to get from my Web service.

Here is the full source:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetInteger2";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetInteger2";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:4711/Service1.asmx";

public int GetInteger2() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("i");
    pi.setValue(123);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
        new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    return Integer.parseInt(result.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Typecast the envelope to SoapPrimitive:

```
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
String strRes = result.toString();
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can Use below code to call the web service and get response .Make sure that your Web Service return the response in **Data Table Format**..This code help you if you using data from **SQL Server** database .If you you using **MYSQL** you need to change one thing just replace word  **NewDataSet** from sentence `obj2=(SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");` by **DocumentElement**

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://localhost/Web_Service.asmx?"; // you can use   IP address instead of localhost
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Function_Name";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("parm_name", prm_value); // Parameter for Method
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //call the eb service Method
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} //Next task is to get Response and format that response

SoapObject obj, obj1, obj2, obj3;
obj = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
obj1 = (SoapObject) obj.getProperty("diffgram");
obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");

for (int i = 0; i < obj2.getPropertyCount(); i++) //the method getPropertyCount() return the number of rows
{
    obj3 = (SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(i);
    obj3.getProperty(0).toString(); //value of column 1
    obj3.getProperty(1).toString(); //value of column 2
    //like that you will get value from each column
}
```

If you have any problem regarding this you can write me..

Answer (score 0):

If more than one result is expected, then the `getResponse()` method will return a `Vector` containing the various responses.

In which case the offending code becomes:

```
Object result = envelope.getResponse();

// treat result as a vector
String resultText = null;
if (result instanceof Vector)
{
    SoapPrimitive element0 = (SoapPrimitive)((Vector) result).elementAt(0);
    resultText = element0.toString();
}

tv.setText(resultText);
```

Answer based on the [ksoap2-android (mosabua fork)](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't call

```
 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

on main Thread.

[Network operations should be done on different Thread.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html)

Create another Thread or AsyncTask to call the method.