# Android WSDL/SOAP service client

Tags: android, soap, service, wsdl

I have some web services that uses WSDL/SOAP for communication. Specifically, I am using PHP and Nusoap to make them. How can I use these web services on Android? I am going to get a new Android phone soon, so I need to know.

It is easy to do it with Windows Mobile and Visual Studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Android doesn't come with SOAP library. However, you can download 3rd party library here:
[https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

If you need help using it, you might find this thread helpful:
[How to call a .NET Webservice from Android using KSOAP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

Answer (score 10):

i founded this tool to auto generate wsdl to android code,

http://www.wsdl2code.com/Example.aspx

```
public void callWebService(){
    SampleService srv1 = new SampleService();
    Request req = new Request();
    req.companyId = "1";
    req.userName = "userName";
    req.password = "pas";
    Response response =  srv1.ServiceSample(req);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I’ve created a new SOAP client for the Android platform, it is use a JAX-WS generated interfaces, but it is only a proof-of-concept yet.

If you are interested, please try the example and/or watch the source: http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home

Update: the version 0.0.4 is out with tutorial:

http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/2012/04/16/Version+0.0.4+released

http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Step+by+step+tutorial

Answer (score 1):

[Icesoap](http://code.google.com/p/icesoap/), which I found yesterday, looks promising. It worked on a basic test, but it lacks more examples.

Comment: I'm getting null pointer Exception on executing a request. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

```
private static  final  String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static  final String URL = "http://example.com/CRM/Service.svc";
private static  final  String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
private static  final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";


//calling web services method

String loginresult=callService(username,password,usertype);


//calling webservices
String callService(String a1,String b1,Integer c1) throws Exception {

            Boolean flag=true;
            do
            {
                try{
                    System.out.println(flag);

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                PropertyInfo pa1 = new PropertyInfo();
                pa1.setName("Username");
                pa1.setValue(a1.toString());

                PropertyInfo pb1 = new PropertyInfo();
                pb1.setName("Password");
                pb1.setValue(b1.toString());

                PropertyInfo pc1 = new PropertyInfo();
                pc1.setName("UserType");
                pc1.setValue(c1);
                System.out.println(c1+"this is integer****s");




                System.out.println("new");
                request.addProperty(pa1);
                request.addProperty(pb1);
                request.addProperty(pc1);



                System.out.println("new2");
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                System.out.println("new3");
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                System.out.println("new4");
                try{
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                    System.out.println(e+"   this is exception");
                }
                System.out.println("new5");
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                result = response.getProperty(0).toString(); 

                flag=false;
                System.out.println(flag);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                    flag=false;
            }
            }
            while(flag);
            return result;

        }  
///
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just completed a android App about wsdl,i have some tips to append:

1.the most important resource is  [www.wsdl2code.com](http://www.wsdl2code.com)

2.you can take you username and password with header, which encoded with Base64,such as :

```
        String USERNAME = "yourUsername";
    String PASSWORD = "yourPassWord";
    StringBuffer auth = new StringBuffer(USERNAME);
    auth.append(':').append(PASSWORD);
    byte[] raw = auth.toString().getBytes();
    auth.setLength(0);
    auth.append("Basic ");
    org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(raw, 0, raw.length, auth);
    List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", auth.toString())); // "Basic V1M6"));

    Vectordianzhan response = bydWs.getDianzhans(headers);
```

3.somethimes,you are not sure either ANDROID code or webserver is wrong, then debug 
is important.in the sample , catching  "XmlPullParserException" ,log "requestDump" and 
"responseDump"in the exception.additionally, you should catch the IP package with adb.

```
    try {
    Logg.i(TAG, "2  ");
    Object response = androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headers); 
    Logg.i(TAG, "requestDump: " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
    Logg.i(TAG, "responseDump: "+ androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
    Logg.i(TAG, "3");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logg.i(TAG, "IOException");
} 
catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
     Logg.i(TAG, "requestDump: " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
     Logg.i(TAG, "responseDump: "+ androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
     Logg.i(TAG, "XmlPullParserException");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set View to register.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    session = new UserSessionManeger(getApplicationContext());     

    login_id= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginid);
    Suponser_id= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sponserid);
    name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    moblie=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    placment= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.placement);
    Adress= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);
    State = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.state);

    city=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
    pincopde=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pincode);
    counntry= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country);

    plantype= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plantype);


    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registration); 
  //  session.createUserLoginSession(info.getCustomerID(),info.getName(),info.getMobile(),info.getEmailID(),info.getAccountType());
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);        

                request.addProperty("LoginCustomerID",login_id.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("SponsorID",Suponser_id.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("Name", name.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("LoginPassword",pass.getText().toString() );
                request.addProperty("MobileNumber",smoblie=moblie.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("Email",email.getText().toString() );
                request.addProperty("Placement", placment.getText().toString()); 
                request.addProperty("address1",  Adress.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("StateID", State.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("CityName",city.getText().toString());

                request.addProperty("Pincode",pincopde.getText().toString());


                request.addProperty("CountryID",counntry.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("PlanType",plantype.getText().toString());



                //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                try {

                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);


                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();  
                    Log.e("value of result", " result"+result);
                    if(result!= null)
                    {


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully register ", 2000).show()  ;

                    }
                    else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try Again..", 2000).show() ;   
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }
    });
    }

  }
```