# How to use SOAP Service android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am new to Android. Can anyone please help me to get started with Soap services with the help of Any example or source code ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484122/android-wsdl-soap-service-client

Answer (score 2):

use this method if your webservice is .Net based:

```
private static SoapObject callWebServiceMethod(String url,
        String namespace, String methodName,
        HashMap<String, Object> parameters, String soapAction)
        throws Exception {

    Log.i("WebService", "URL: " + url);
    Log.i("WebService", "MethodName: " + methodName);

    URL myurl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = myurl.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(20 * 1000);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
    int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        httpConnection.disconnect();
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);

        if (parameters != null) {
            String[] keys = new String[0];
            keys = (String[]) parameters.keySet().toArray(keys);
            Object[] vals = (Object[]) parameters.values().toArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
                request.addProperty(keys[i], vals[i]);
                Log.i("WebService", keys[i] + ": " + vals[i]);
            }
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,
                TimeOutInSeconds * 1000);


        androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);


        SoapObject so = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        return so;

    }
    else
    {
        httpConnection.disconnect();

    }

}
```

for downloading Ksoap library [use this link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Answer (score 1):

For use in SOAP Service in android you need to see Below Reference to Parse Soap:

Link To [Soap service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484122/android-wsdl-soap-service-client)

Link to [Step by Step Use](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr)

Get ksoap jar to use in your android project from this [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Below is class for call Web-service for soap using ksoap library .