# How to call SOAP service in my log-In Application? android

Tags: java, android

Please Help me in My problem

How to call SOAP service in my application.

Log - In application

Where username and password and click the button then check it if 
the password is correct or incorrect.

Thank you for some Information and examples you share to me.

this images I want to to my application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Android doesn't have it's own SOAP library, you should use 3rd party library.
This should help : [Android WSDL/SOAP service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484122/android-wsdl-soap-service-client)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Third Party library for SOAP web service called ksoap2.

ksoap2-android provides a lightweight and efficient SOAP library for the Android platform.

Here is the good example for SOAP Webservice in android.

[SOAP ANDROID TUTORIAL.](http://p-xr.com/android-development-tutorial-reading-soap-services/)