# Request and Parsing list response data SOAP in android

Tags: android, parsing, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm still new in android and SOAP webservice...

I want to ask about give request and parsing report in my webservice.

Here is the raw webservice request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:ZfmGenerateUuid>
          <IvNumber>?</IvNumber>
          <OListUuid>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <item>
                <NoHandle>?</NoHandle>
                <Uuid>?</Uuid>
                <Uuid2>?</Uuid2>
            </item>
          </OListUuid>
      </urn:ZfmGenerateUuid>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

If we set `IvNumber = 4`, and no input for NoHandle, Uuid, and Uuid2 like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:ZfmGenerateUuid>
              <IvNumber>4</IvNumber>
              <OListUuid>
                 <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                 <item>
                    <NoHandle></NoHandle>
                    <Uuid></Uuid>
                    <Uuid2></Uuid2>
                 </item>
              </OListUuid>
         </urn:ZfmGenerateUuid>
     </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Result will be like this

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header/>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <n0:ZfmGenerateUuidResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <OListUuid>
             <item>
                <NoHandle>1</NoHandle>
                <Uuid>080027F5350A1ED2B98EBC7B96440955</Uuid>
                <Uuid2>080027f5-350a-1ed2-b98e-bc7b96440955</Uuid2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <NoHandle>2</NoHandle>
                <Uuid>080027F5350A1ED2B98EBC7B96442955</Uuid>
                <Uuid2>080027f5-350a-1ed2-b98e-bc7b96442955</Uuid2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <NoHandle>3</NoHandle>
                <Uuid>080027F5350A1ED2B98EBC7B96444955</Uuid>
                <Uuid2>080027f5-350a-1ed2-b98e-bc7b96444955</Uuid2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <NoHandle>4</NoHandle>
                <Uuid>080027F5350A1ED2B98EBC7B96446955</Uuid>
                <Uuid2>080027f5-350a-1ed2-b98e-bc7b96446955</Uuid2>
            </item>
         </OListUuid>
      </n0:ZfmGenerateUuidResponse>
   </soap-env:Body>
   </soap-env:Envelope>
```

Is there any tutorial or code that make me can give request and consume that SOAP?

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Android training site](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) at these topics:

[Performing Network Operations](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html)

[Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

For more answers with SOAP request please look at this question: ["Android WSDL/SOAP service client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484122/android-wsdl-soap-service-client)

Comment: i have already try with the easier  one...

with only one parameter request and one parameter response...

and its worked.
but i didn't get one tutorial that give response like i have...