# Android Consume WSDL that returns xml

Tags: android

My client has shared with me a webservice with its methods so that i could integrate with it. Are there any way to consume this webservice?. A simple sample would be interesting.
I have to mention that the webservice returns an xml response so how do i unserialize to use the response?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:red="http://myhosting/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <red:begin>

         <!--Optional:-->
         <username>w123456789</username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <password>1111</password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mac>123456789123456</mac>
         <phone>941880834</phone>
      </red:begin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WSDL/SOAP service client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484122/android-wsdl-soap-service-client)

Comment: This url focus on an specific language programmming. What i have is already a wsdl no matter what language. What i need to know is a way to consume a webservice and take advantage of it to use it with my widgets or place the result on arrays.

Comment: Each language will have to handle it different. Android does not work with WSDL/SOAP out of the box

Comment: what's the solution then?

Comment: you didnt really pose a question that we can answer. Why does it have to be language agnostic? Each platform has its own language

Comment: Because my customer just gave me the wsdl but didnt tell me anything about the language was written the wsdl

Comment: The language that wrote the wsdl has nothing to do with your ability to consume it

Comment: Are there any solución to consume my wsdl that returns n xml?