# How to pass parameter to a webservice using ksoap2?

Tags: java, android, web-services, parameters, ksoap2

I'm using Eclipse IDE to develop an android app. I'm trying to connect to a .net webservice.  I'm using ksoap2 version 2.3

When I'm calling a webmethod with no parameters, it works fine. When I come to pass a parameter to the webmethod, I get null (while debugging the webservice I discovered that) and I get a null from the webmethod in the client side code.

Code:

```
package com.examples.hello;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Innovation/HRService/stringBs";

 private static final String METHOD_NAME = "stringBs";

 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://Innovation/HRService/";
 private static final String URL = "http://196.205.5.170/mdl/hrservice.asmx";
 TextView tv;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
     call();

 }

 public void call()
 {
         try {

          SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
          //PropertyInfo PI = new PropertyInfo();

             //request.addProperty("a", "myprop");

             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             envelope.dotNet=true;
             envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;


             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();


             String results = result.toString();
             tv.setText( ""+results); 
         } catch (Exception e) {
             tv.setText(e.getMessage());
             }
     }


}
```

Why do I get the null response, how do I pass a parameter to a webservice using ksoap2?

Comment: Maybe this thread can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2 I am also starting to use ksoap2 based on eclipse from scratch.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of

```
    request.addProperty("a", "myprop");
```

try using

```
    request.addProperty("arg0", "myprop");
```

I'm not an expect on ksoap2 but i'm pretty sure this sets the value of the first parameter to your web service function. Has worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 5):

Calling webservice by passing parameters from j2me

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://www.webserviceX.NET", "GetCitiesByCountry");
String soapAction = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry";

request.addProperty("CountryName", "india");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.bodyOut = request;
envelope.dotNet = true;

HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx");
ht.debug = true;
//System.err.println( ht.requestDump );

ht.call(soapAction,envelope);
System.out.println("####################: " +envelope.getResponse());
//SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been working with this for 2 days now and i finally got the solution. I submit my complete code and hope this will help. It Can pass Parameters and get response.

**Inside the WebService file in .net C#:**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://something/webservice/v1")]

[WebMethod]
public DateTime[] Function(Guid organizationId, Guid categoryId)
    {
        return ...;
    }
```

**Inside the Android code:**

```
private final static String URL = "http://something/WebServices/WebService.asmx";
private final static String NAMESPACE = "http://something/webservice/v1";


public ArrayList<Object> getSoapObject(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, Map<String, String> parameters){

try {

        ArrayList<Object> sol = new ArrayList<Object>();
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        if(parameters != null){
            for (Entry<String, String> para : parameters.entrySet()) {
                request.addProperty(para.getKey(), para.getValue());
            }
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        Log.d("Body", envelope.bodyOut.toString());

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

            for(int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++){
                sol.add(result.getProperty(i));
            }

            return sol;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }       
    }


    public void getMenuEndDate(String orgId, String categoryId){

        Date startDate = null;
        Date endDate = null;

        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("organizationId", orgId);
        parameters.put("categoryId", categoryId);


        ArrayList<Object> sol = getSoapObject("Function", "http://something/webservice/v1/Function", parameters);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        try {
            startDate = (Date)dateFormatter.parse(sol.get(0).toString());
            endDate = (Date)dateFormatter.parse(sol.get(1).toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception i Date-Formatering");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Things to check:

- Are the parameters named exactly the same as what is expected in the Web Service?
- Check if you use Trailing "/" for the Namespace. Have the same in you application.

Answer (score 4):

Try commenting out the line:

> envelope.dotNet=true;

I did the same thing you did and when I read about this property being a really ugly hack, I commented it out for testing purposes and my parameter got passed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to declare parameter type in client code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "mymethod"); 
PropertyInfo p = new PropertyInfo();
p.setName("param_name_from_webservice");
p.setValue(true);
p.setType(Boolean.class);
request.addProperty(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

In here Problem With the Order of Codes You Wrote, Don't Worry Try this, It's Worked for me.

```
private class ConversionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private SoapPrimitive response;
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);


        request.addProperty("a","5");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;

        try {
            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            response = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        temperatureTxt.setText("Status: " + response);
    }
}
```