# sending soap request to .net webservice

Tags: android, web-services

i developed an android application..now i want to send soap request to webservice...i have an OUTLETID value in string format..so how to create root element and child for that string....web service method in below format....pls any one help me...

my web service method code below....

```
public string GetOutletID(string outlet)
    {
        xDoc.LoadXml("<PMS></PMS>");
        XmlNode Root = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        XmlElement head = xDoc.CreateElement("EMENU");
        Root.AppendChild(head);

        XmlElement dt = xDoc.CreateElement("DATETIME");
        dt.InnerText = Date;
        head.AppendChild(dt);

        elem = null;
        elem = xDoc.CreateElement("ID");
        elem.InnerText = "1";
        head.AppendChild(elem);

        elem = null;
        elem = xDoc.CreateElement("REQTYPE");
        elem.InnerText = "OUTLETID";
        head.AppendChild(elem);

        elem = null;
        elem = xDoc.CreateElement("OUTLETID");
        elem.InnerText = outlet;
        head.AppendChild(elem);
        return xDoc.InnerXml.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PropertyInfo Class to achieve it, the answer is from previously asked questions from StackOverFlow, check this link [Passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108527/how-to-pass-parameter-to-a-webservice-using-ksoap2)