# Consuming a web service in Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, apache-axis, webservices-client

I have written a we service and I have the WSDL file.
I am new to android programming and I want to use my web service functions in my mobile application.
What are the different methods that I can use? What can be the best option and please give me some good reference for that.

Comment: Here's the library https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/  here're some posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108527/how-to-pass-parameter-to-a-webservice-using-ksoap2 here's the tutorial http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html