# Web Services with Android - why no support for WSDL?

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl

I'm creating a Client/Server application with Android (Client) and WCF (Web Service).
From reading quite alot of discussions, I'm under the impression that there is no tool available to create the web service client in android automatically from a WSDL file.

If this is the situation, what is the easiest approach for creating a communication infrastructure between the client and server, that can be updated easily in the future (plain GET, REST, use SOAP and manually parse responses)
Initially, I wanted to build the web service and have the client created automatically with the provided WSDL file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no tool for automatic client generation based on a WSDL.
Android doesn't come with any soap related library.
BTW you can look for [ksoap2-Android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) libraries and see if it's suitable for you.

More infos about using ksoap with Android should be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

Comment: Im also design the Web Service. I think it would be easier to just do plain GET instead of manually parsing the SOAP calls as described in the link..

Comment: IMHO keeping the client/server protocol as simple as possible is always the best approach. Less things to do means less memory usage. Usually I use GET with an simple xml or a json as response