# Calling WCF in Android Application

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf

i am new to WCF
i have created WCF which retrieve data from database and this will execute thru asp.net application

now, i want to use this WCF in my android application
can anybody tell me what should i do ?

i have study but i got little hint, about SOAP and REST.

so which would be preferable for me ? can anybody give me hint or code ?
i need ready working code snippet

```
    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI("http://localhost:3997/AWS_WCF_Service.svc");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri + "/SayHello");
    httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");        
    HttpResponse response = null;   
response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
```

Thank YOu

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how might depend on which version of ASP.Net you're using, but you will need your Web app to expose your WCF objects using a service. If you are using 4.0, either SOAP or REST services are options (Web Service or WebAPI service). If you want a philosophical debate about their respective merits, this might be a place to start: [SOAP or REST for Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services), but since both can return JSON, either is probably fine for your Android app.

I have .Net 3.5 myself so I've mostly been using the Web Service version (with an .asmx file), and found the following link immensely useful:

[Android -- How to access data in an ASP.NET database via app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311681/android-how-to-access-data-in-an-asp-net-database-via-app)

The accepted answer on that thread got me set up with a basic Web Service and little Android app in one afternoon! (This was admittedly with me having some little knowledge of both)

If you want a RESTful service and you have .Net 4.0, I suspect you could achieve your aim by following a tutorial on the subject (like this one http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), and then using the Android code from the link above.

(Something worth bearing in mind when working with ASP.Net services returning JSON is that the returned object will be wrapped in an object called "d" - see [Why do ASP.NET JSON web services return the result in 'd'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588589/why-do-asp-net-json-web-services-return-the-result-in-d). I haven't used XML so I don't know if there are any issues for that format.)