# Eclipse Android Plugin calling a WCF Web Service in basicHttpBinding

Tags: java, android, wcf, web-services, eclipse

I am completely new to the Eclipse world and I haven't found very many usefull resources on calling a web service written in .NET.

I'm trying to port an app over I wrote for the new Windows 7 Phone to the Android OS. I have Eclipse and the Android SDK. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I might call my WCF web service from my Java app?

The WCF service is very basic and uses Soap 1.1 (basic http binding)

Thanks!

Comment: If possible please update your service to RestFul service and use the json to call the url from android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't come with SOAP library. However, you can download 3rd party library here:
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

If you need help using it, you might find this thread helpful:
[How to call a .NET Webservice from Android using KSOAP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

Comment: he asked to call WCF web service. Is it possible to call a WCF using soap?