# passing parameters to url in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.I want to pass data to url 
http://services.mascus.com/api/mascusapi.asmx?op=AddContactRequest
I have used postdata method.
Below is the code i have applied

```
package com.xib;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
public class TestHttpPost extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        postData();

    }
    public void postData() { 
        Log.d("hi", "value of array is ");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("//http://services.mascus.com/api/mascusapi.asmx?op=OpenSession");


        try 
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "xib"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "efi99LKW"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.d("hi", "value of array is ");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.e("hi", "value of array is ->"+convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } 
    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
    throws IOException {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
         * Reader.read(char[] buffer) method. We iterate until the
         * Reader return -1 which means there's no more data to
         * read. We use the StringWriter class to produce the string.
         */
        if (is != null)
        {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
          char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {        
            return "";
        }
      }

  }
```

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: This isn't exactly a question and has been closed as such. In the future, please _clearly_ state what you hope to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke soap methods from android you can use Ksoap2 
[How to call a .NET Webservice from Android using KSOAP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

Answer (score 0):

You have coded for an HTTP based web service And you are going to use a SOAP based web service. So code for a SOAP based web service and pass your WSDL URL when you make a request.

You will have all relative information in your WSDL.