# Consuming WebServices using SOAP

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, ksoap

How can i consume a WebService in Android using KSOAP?

Thanks

Comment: See [this](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [Consume KSoap WebService in Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html). Will be helpfull...