# How to send a JSON object over HttpClient Request with Android?

Tags: android, json, post, request

I want to send the JSON text {} to a web service and read the response. How can I do this from android? What are the steps such as creating request object, setting content headers, etc.

My code is here

```
public void postData(String result,JSONObject obj) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);

    String json=obj.toString();

    try {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(result.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString()); 
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httppost.setEntity(se); 

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.i("tag", temp);


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

what mistake i have done plz correct me because it shows me an bad request error
but when i do post in poster it shows me status as Successfull 200 ok

Comment: Try setting this type `entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
      "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));`

Comment: @Soni No its not working fine for me , i tried it but it shows me Bad Request error

Comment: @Soni the only mistake had done is im not setHeader like this in below post httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do this with

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Also, the `new HttpPost()` takes the web service URL as argument.

Answer (score 1):

In the try catch loop, I did this:

```
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
         "https://www.placeyoururlhere.com");
         post.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json" );
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new
         ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json));
         post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
         HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

         response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

You can add your nameValurPairs according to how many fields you have.
Typically the JSON might become really huge, which I will then suggest gzipping it then sending, but if your JSON is fairly small and always the same size the above should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a web service and not RestAPI call then, you can get the WSDL file from the server and use a SOAP Stub generator to do all the work of creating the Request objects and the networking code for you, for example WSClient++

If you wish to do it by yourself then things get a little tricky. Android doesn't come with SOAP library. 
However, you can download 3rd party library here: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

If you need help using it, you might find this thread helpful: [How to call a .NET Webservice from Android using KSOAP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

If its a REST-API Call like POST or GET to be more specific then its is very simple 
Just pass a JSON Formatted String object in you function and use org.json package to parse the response string for you.

Hope this helps.