# Bad Request when sending json object with authentication on android

Tags: android, json, authentication, http-post, httpclient

I am getting the error `bad request` when I try to send a json object with authentication. I had a look at [How to send a JSON object over HttpClient Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389842/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-httpclient-request-with-android) but it does not solve my problem.

```
public void getServerData() throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    ArrayList<String> stringData = new ArrayList<String>();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    byte[] data = "myusername:mypassword".getBytes("UTF-8");
    String encoding = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://url/email_check.json");
    postMethod.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

    postMethod.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("email","somebody@email.com");


    postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
    String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);
    Log.e("response :", response);
    }
```

The line `String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);` causes a `ClientProtocolException` as follows:

```
cause: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
detailMessage: Bad Request
stackState: (id=830103290336)
stackTrace: null
statusCode: 400
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You need to include the full error (including status code and message) to your question. Also, if you have access to the server, find the corresponding exception in the logs and include that in your question as well.