# Android and ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I need a simple step by step on how to implement ksoap 2.

- What .jar file should I download and how should I add it to my application in eclipse.
- I have a .Net WS that I want to connect to. The WS is of type .svc

Please help me with the first steps......

Comment: I get this error message:
E/AndroidRuntime(7291): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

When trying to execute this line:   
new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

I use the ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Answer (score 0):

hey just google on this you will get good tutorials.

check this [Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

[blog link](http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html)