# How to develop webservice for Android

Tags: android, web-services, webservice-client

I am developing an Android application associated with a website.  There is a registration module in my application. When ever a user enters the details in the form, the form data should be stored on our server.

Somebody has suggested that writing a WebService is a good way to connect.  But I am not aware of WebServices.  How do you write a WebService?  Do we need any special software? Or can it be done in eclipse itself? After writing the WebService, where does it need to be saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these:

[How to call a webservice from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

[How to call a .net webservice from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android)

Are a good starting point on how to call webservices from Android.

A WebService runs on your website, not on the Android device, so the technology required to write the service would be restricted by the technology that your website supported.  As you haven't mentioned that it's hard to give advice.  Using .Net and WCF is a fairly approachable way to write webservices, but may not be appropriate for your problem.

It's also worth noting that the Android API may have moved on since these questions were first posted, to improve support for calling webservices.

Answer (score 0):

use this link:  for android client side and also in j2ee netbeans server side as jax-ws..

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html

and add  ksoap2.jar file in project lib folder

Hope it helps u.