# Insert data into server using webservice through android

Tags: android, web-services

I have a web method in .net `"InsertData("parameter1,"parameter2"")"` .how can I implement it through android.
              How can I insert data directly in server through android using .net `webservice`.

How can I pass parameter values?

Answer (score 0):

maybe that helps:

[How to call a .NET web service from android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android)