# What are the best practices to connect Android application and .NET world using web services?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, web-services

Let's assume I have some sort of user data, like list of user messages and some metadata (coordinates and etc.)

Right now I have to expose some API for Android clients to get/filter user data. So I am wondering what are the best practices to do that? Should I use WCF Data Services, REST WCF or Atom Feed WCF? or something else? What I need is to create really easy to use API (which is supported by some libraries) in terms of developing for Android clients and for other mobile platform in the future, like WP7.

Thanks

Comment: I personally find it easier to consume JSon APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using KSoap2.

See this tutorial:

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

Answer (score 0):

As Dyonisos said ksoap2, and in the server side ASP.NET web services, it should do the job. BTW there is a lot of examples on the Internet for using those two techs.

http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html

[How to call a .NET web service from android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android)

http://bimbim.in/post/2010/10/08/Android-Calling-Web-Service-with-complex-types.aspx