# Connecting android to a web-service

Tags: c#, android, xml, web-services, httpwebrequest

I am developing an android application, I want to connect it to a web-service ,
Any ideas about how to make a web request and receive the response?
N.B: I want to sen a XML file to the web-service and receive from it too.
Thanks in advance

Comment: With webservice do you mean SOAP web service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android

Answer (score 0):

For connecting a website use the following code

```
             URL url = new URL("http://www.myweb.com");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);    // 5 seconds
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");       
                conn.connect();
                BufferedReader rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String line;

                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                  //data of the page will be returned in line, do whatever u want here
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

i founded this tool to auto generate wsdl to android code,

http://www.wsdl2code.com/Example.aspx

```
public void callWebService(){
    SampleService srv1 = new SampleService();
    Request req = new Request();
    req.companyId = "1";
    req.userName = "userName";
    req.password = "pas";
    Response response =  srv1.ServiceSample(req);
}
```