# Using .NET web-services in Android application

Tags: android, .net, web-services

My company has set-up a web-service to get and set user data using .NET.

I am required to use this service in my Android application. I am totally new to the concept of web-services and communication between the device and the server.

I downloaded the ksoap library jar file and referred it in my android project. What do I do next ?
How do I set up the connection ? How do I exchange data ?

I saw a few tutorials but their coding is either incomplete or beyond my understanding. 
Can anyone provide me with a simple tutorial or a working code for the implementation of the service in my application ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should first check what the .NET web service expects to receive and what it sends. It doesn't have to be soap. It could be a simple xml or something else. also there are other examples in this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android

Comment: I clicked on the link in the service and I got this as the response.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetControlResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetControlResult>
        <Id>int</Id>
        <Belt>boolean</Belt>
 </GetControlResult>
    </GetControlResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: check this question you will find what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look @ http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

It pretty much explains the android part and interestingly it is talking to a .NET Webservice (You shouldn't ideally bother about the service though).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I have to consider whether the data is being transferred through SOAP or XML... ? for eg, the first comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I finally did it! :D