# I have a asp.net Webservice which returns me XML. What should i use in Android and how to parse it and how to assidn it to a list view?

Tags: android, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a .NET web service from android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android)

I have a asp.net Webservice which returns me XML. What should i use in Android and how to parse it and how to assidn it to a list view? Can any one help me in this with sample application.

thanks,
Ravinder

Comment: I did homework for you: [How to call .NET webservice with android](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+call+.NET+webservice+in+android&submit=search)