# How to call .net webservice from android?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services

I created a demo .net webservice in visual studio and I'm trying to run in my local browser using localhost. This gives one of the errors below:

1) XML pull parser exception when my address = IP + portnumber

2) Unknown host exception when my address = emulator port + localport

3) Connect exception failed to connect local host when my address = localhost + port number

How to create AVD using CMD?

Comment: private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://my ip:56044//Service1.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://http://10.0.2.2:8080//Service1.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:56044/Service1.asmx";    When i use this addresses one by one at that time application gives three different error as per in my question, I run my service on localhost using IIS express and browser.What is perfect solution for that.

Comment: My program cannot run because localhost cannot understand by emulator?

Comment: I also tried this code   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android                         but not able to find perfect solution!!! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If You Want to call Rest Webservice than Here Is the Code:



class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            @Override
            //  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android
            protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                String responseString = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        out.close();
                        responseString = out.toString();
                    } else{
                        //Closes the connection.
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return responseString;
            }




If You Want to call WCF/asmx Webservice than Here Is the Code:
Here You have to use KSOAP2 library

private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "[http://10.0.2.2:8085/Service1.svc][1]";
//Use Service1.asmx for asmx service
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "GetData";


                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                try {

                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    Log.i("myApp_Responce...", response.toString());

                    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText(response.toString());
                      } catch (Exception e)
                      {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                       }
```