# How to fetch .net web service in android?

Tags: android, .net

I have a web service written in .net whose url is http://aaplasatara.absoftwaresolution.com/Service.svc?wsdl
I want to fetch the data from web service and save it to sqlite database.
I don't want to use php.Please give solution...

Answer (score 0):

Have you googled it?

Here you can find solutions:
[solution 1](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/)
[solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1052730/1374065)

Please take a look and see if you find any of these helpful.